# Convert all csvs from google drive

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am trying to search for all csvs in my google drive and store them in a specific folder with **spreadsheet format**.

I have successfully tried the same for a specific csv by name but now I want all csvs and I dont know how to do it.

```
function convert() {
    var file = DriveApp.searchFiles("*filename*").next();
    var name = file.getName();
    var ID = file.getId();
    var xBlob = file.getBlob();
    var newFile = { title : name+'_converted',
        key : ID,
        parents: [{"id": "**folder id**"}]
    }
    file = Drive.Files.insert(newFile,xBlob, {convert: true});
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the number of CSV files? When you want to retrieve only CSV files, you can use ``mimeType='text/csv'`` as the search query. But I think that if the number of CSV files are large, the script might be required to be matched to the situation. So, at first, I asked about the number of CSV files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code you listed above is already working an retrieving a single CSV file at a time, all you need to do is wrap it in a loop that will continue running through files until they are all processed. It should look something like this:

```
// You will need to use the syntax in Google's developer guide to search with searchFiles:
// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchfilesparams

// This should find any files with the text '.csv'. If there are false positives, you can change this to 'mimeType contains "csv"' to look for files with either application/csv or text/csv mime types
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains ".csv"');
// The code inside the while statement will run on each file until there are no more files in the array from searchFiles
while (files.hasNext()) {
    // Gets the next file in the array of files
    var file = files.next();
    var name = file.getName();
    var ID = file.getId();
    var xBlob = file.getBlob();
    var newFile = { title : name+'_converted',
                 key : ID,
                 parents: [{"id": "**folder id**"}] 
    }
    file = Drive.Files.insert(newFile,xBlob, {convert: true});
}
```

Does this answer your question?